# Possible to update numberOfSteps for WKInterfaceSlider after awakeWithContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I've noticed that the only way to change a WKInterfaceSlider's number of steps is to call setNumberOfSteps: in awakeWithContext.

If i try to update it any other time the numberOfSteps does not update on screen. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug. You have not much control over UI in WatchKit.
If we change `numberOfSteps` property `WKInterfaceSlider` will not get updated but it will in 'broken' state. On picture below I changed `numberOfSteps` to 5 from 3. Notice broken fill of segment.

[image]

Comment: Yep, same thing I get.